# Mail from the same address is not delivered

Tags: php, outlook.com

I use Outlook.com on my own domain. It's a shop. Whenever a customer makes an order, I send two e-mails:

- I send him/her the order confirmation (FROM orders@[mydomain] TO the customer's email address)
- I send a copy to myself (FROM orders@[mydomain] TO orders@[mydomain] (the same address))

The second mail never gets delivered.

When I substitute the TO address to any other address within [mydomain], it also never gets delivered. When I substitute the TO address to anything else, it works. Also when I don't try to send the first e-mail and only send the second one, it still never gets delivered.

I checked the junk folder and the deleted mails folder - they're empty.

Can you please help me with this? Thank you very much.

Comment: You might want to check the `Sent` folder instead.

Comment: Thank you - I did, nothing there.

Comment: Can you BCC orders@mydomain.com on the first?

Comment: Tried that too; no, the e-mail still doesn't get delivered. Actually I switched to this two-mail version because the bcc didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked to see if your server has an internal mail system where these are being delivered instead of them actually leaving the server to be delivered to you? Also, this could be because your domain name does not allow relayed messages (meaning that your server isn't set up to actually send mail from your domain name, so it is being relayed through your domain name). There may be an email log file on the server somewhere that shows the error.

Comment: Well it's Outlook.com that handles mails for my domain... Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to place your email in the BCC: on the original email?

```
*BCC:orders@[mydomain]*
```

Comment: Yes, didn't work. Actually I switched to this two-mail version because BCC didn't work.